# Windows 11 21H2 upgrade to 22H2 failing @ 64%

Tags: windows

I have a bunch of machines running Win11 21H2 which need updating to 22H2. I'm using WSUS and have downloaded Windows 11, version 22H2 x64 2023-10B.

For 30 minutes the machine will download and install the upgrade and complete any other bits it needs to compile, after successful completion of the initial phase I then reboot.

During the next phase there's a couple of reboots and the upgrade process appears to be going well, the percentage indicator increases fairly quickly, and then suddenly stops at 64%. It says Updating drivers and just sits there for about 2 hours, eventually increasing to 87%, and that's were it remains for an eternity.

I haven't had any problems running Win11 21H2 these past few months, with no driver issues or dodgy applications. This should be a simple in-place update to 22H2 on an OS that is stable, I don't understand why it would hang.

I've disabled AV and put the test machine in an OU that removes Group Policies.

The only entry in Event Viewer pertaining to the upgrade is: WindowsUpdateClient, Installation failure: error 0xc1900101 : Event ID 20.
The error is somewhat generic and hasn't helped find an answer.

A new 22H2 image has been created which installs and works without issue.... however, I don't won't to rebuild all the machines.

Comment: `A new 22H2 image has been created` what about testing the upgrade using the traditional process outside of WSUS? Or checking the setup logs to determine the component and/or driver that is being updated?

Comment: The environment isn't connected to the internet, we're limited to WSUS in an 'offline' configuration. I tried downloading the latest iso and updating from that but I got the same issue. Sifting through the setup logs hasn't revealed anything to go on, yet, however, I'm still looking through them... just in case I've missed something.